# At the First Attempt to Create the BIOS?

Tags: os

**Reformulated:**

The question was directed to the first attempt of creating a BIOS (Basic Input/Output System).

Simply, the first "thing", to have the first "function", when it is not written in an operating system already.

They may be using machines, to have the display turn its colors. Then to showcase a symbol. Which then may continue into a character set. The switching of symbols, or also pages may become possible. The setting of different colors may become possible. And then it may continue taking forms into a BIOS system.

I have rewritten this one more time, nevertheless, I am having troubles to formulate on this topic, it can be considered as resolved.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Is your question about the low-level working of a computer, or about how one develops an OS, or something else entirely? The addendum and the last part of the question only add to the confusion.

Comment: Please consider restructuring the question to specifically address the Electronics question you want to ask. This is too confusing.

Comment: You will probably get further looking at actual cases of modern embedded operating systems and associated bootloaders, historic BIOSs, and modern BIOS replacements than in sticking to some theoretical "action and function" model of what you expect to find.  It's not that the theoretical model doesn't have validity, but you need to understand something about the realities of possible implementation before it will have enough context.

Comment: I have tried reformulated the question. I am having troubles formulating and articulating on this topic. The question is indeed directed at the first "thing" which is done to manage the first ´function´ and take it further till to an action BIOS system - when it is not done in Windows.

Comment: In the above comment "actual BIOS system" was meant.

Comment: I don't see a question in this question. The sentence that ends with a question mark doesn't seem to contain a clear question. Also, I'm not sure what you mean with the word "constellations" --- in English, this means arrangements of stars in the sky. Maybe if you get someone to help you with the English vocabulary it could make the question more clear?

Comment: Thanks for the notice, The Photon. I have rewritten it one more time, it can be considered as resolved. I had troubles tapping out this topic and would consequently mess up the writing. The making up of attributes and concluding in "something", was meant with the incorrectly used word "constellations".

Comment: If you look at something portable like u-boot, you will find that the "first steps" depend highly on the needs of a given hardware platform, but will often include things like setting basic processor configuration, enabling a clock multiplier, configuring dynamic memory and a memory management unit if present, etc.  You may also see things like copying the program from relatively slow flash memory to ram (possibly with a decompression step) and then jumping into that copy.

Comment: Bringing up displays is often done fairly late since a lot of peripheral configuration is typically required, though simple things like LEDs (or LED backlights) could be flashed early to indicate that the system is starting.  Systems under development will often try to bring up a serial port as early as possible to provide status information or accept options, long before the device's own display is usable.

Comment: Thanks, Chris Stratton, your writing does clarify the scenario on my side. I had problems tapping out this topic. If for example a display has a hardware controller connected to it, and the hardware controller can switch the color on the display - let's say from "green" to "yellow". How would this basic example now turn into a software, which can be saved on a hard drive disk, so that the colors can be switched by using the software with the mouse controller?

Comment: To extend the prior written comment a bit. The color on the display can be switched with one key of the typing keyboard serving as the controller, already. Where it does require to have two colors defined, and the function to switch the color. Where, comprehensively considering, that the software is saved on the hard drive disk, the "booting" does become a question, which is something the BIOS does take over.

Comment: You seem to have too many disparate topics intermixed here, such as displays, disks, keyboards.  Pick up a simple embedded board, try get just one of these peripherals working before worrying about the next, and you will start to gain some useful perspective.

Comment: I am not sure what you are addressing, quite a bit is narrowed down already. You seem to be addressing a different topic.

Answer (score 1):

The term BIOS originated with CP/M back in the 1970's but it is mostly associated with the IBM PC (1981) and its various clones and successors.

The BIOS gets control when the computer first starts up, via the reset vector of the processor at f000h:ffffh (or is rebooted using the Ctrl-Alt-Del key combination).

The BIOS then does a POST (Power On Self Test) which verifies the processor, various peripherals such as DMA, interrupt controller, and main memory are okay, and that there is a keyboard present.

In the original IBM PC there were no floppy disks, so the BIOS provided routines to interface with a cassette drive.  A year or so later, floppy disks were added and the BIOS was upgraded to provide various functions such as formatting a disk, reading and writing sectors, etc.

Once the POST was finished, the BIOS would use its own disk routines to read in the first sector of the disk which contains the boot code -- this is then used to load in the operating system (e.g. MS-DOS, and later Windows).

Once MS-DOS was loaded in, the BIOS provided functions to interface with the video display, disk drives, serial ports, printer ports, keyboard, and real-time clock and other hardware.  The interface was done via software interrupts -- for example, INT 10h was used for video, and INT 13h was used for floppy disk services.

Later, routines were added to detect PS/2 keyboards and mice, and still later, USB keyboards and mice during boot-up.  Likewise, the floppy disk routines were enhanced to interface hard drives, then CD/DVD drives, and finally USB flash drives as boot options.

The original 16-bit versions of Windows (which essentially sat on top of MS-DOS) also made use of BIOS services.  32-bit versions of Windows have their own I/O routines and do not use BIOS services.

So by the definition of the BIOS given above, this is not really a OS, but just I/O routines which provide services to an OS (hence the name Basic Input/Output System).  To have a minimal disk OS, you would need to add a file system and the ability to run programs off of disk.  (The command line interpreter would be loaded off of disk when the OS starts up.)  These functions could be included in the BIOS, but it is better to keep it as minimal as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the run down. To extend the asked question a bit. I do draw the analogy to audio frequencies, where a certain constellation of frequency waves in a specific range may cause a tone, which then can have its definition. It may have a similar principle with electricity where certain constellation may cause something specific to happen, when then again may have its own definition and perhaps a hardware button representing it. Till it does move into a user interface which does get controlled with a mouse. Yet, I am wondering if this procedure can be quick.(?)

Comment: I have rewritten it one more time, it can be considered as resolved. I had troubles tapping out this topic and would consequently mess up the writing. The making up of attributes and concluding in "something", was meant with the incorrectly used word "constellations".

Comment: "Contestallations" would be obscure though not incorrect terminology - we might be more inclined to say input vector.  The real issue though is that is an almost mathematical view of a system, while the questions you are asking are all about implementation detail.

Comment: The barrier is indeed one, to be crossed. Where, the information mentioned in this thread have contributed to have the barrier more outlined and better understood.